# How to create a datetime macro variable in SAS

Tags: sas

```
%let mydate = "01JUN2021 00:00:00.000"dt;
```

This does not work. How do I create a datetime macro variable without using `proc sql` or `data` step?

Comment: Looks valid to me.  Define not working.

Comment: It doesn't understand it as a Datetime variable but as a string

Comment: Show the code you are using where resolving the macro variable's value into SAS code does not work.

Comment: Are you trying to have the macro variable convert it to an actual SAS datetime? If so, you'll need to convert it manually since the macro facility only understands text as strings. Use `%sysfunc(putn("01JUN2021 00:00:00.000"dt, 32.));`

Comment: Definitely need to give us the code and the error messages for this to answer it.

Comment: Pretty sure they're running into one of the use cases where using the literal syntax confuses SAS when you try to resolve the value later... for this reason I recommend never using the literal approach above because it doesn't perform the conversion and store the numeric value to the macro var.  It saves the literal text...

Comment: Note that to the macro processor everything is a string.  If you are trying to use the value with macro logic make sure you are explicitly calling `%sysevalf()` because the `%eval()` macro function that is used implicitly by %IF and %WHILE and %UNTIL does not recognize literals or non integer values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pure macro solution is:

```
%let mydate = %sysfunc(dhms(%sysfunc(mdy(6,1,2021)), 0, 0, 0));
%put &=mydate; * PRINTS THE UNFORMATTED VALUE STORED;
%put %sysfunc(sum(&mydate), datetime22.); * PRINTS THE DATETIME VALUE FORMATTED;
```

Output:

```
MYDATE=1938124800
01JUN2021:00:00:00
```

You can of course perform the `dhms()` and `mdy()` functions on separate lines if that is clearer for you.

Compare this to what your orginal code is doing:

```
%let mydate="01jan2021:00:00:00"dt;
%put &=mydate;
```

Prints:

```
MYDATE="01jan2021:00:00:00"dt
```

Notice how in your approach the string `"01jan2021:00:00:00"dt` has been saved into the macro variable, rather than the actual numeric date value `1938124800`?  Sometimes when you use your approach SAS gets confused when you try to use the value and it is unable to translate the literal to a numeric date value.

Answer (score 0):

try `%let mydate = '1Jan2021:0:0:1'dt`
Note that it uses single quotes & theres no space between date and time

Comment: Single or double don't matter, both are fine.  The colon is more technically correct but isn't really a problem.

Comment: There are some edge cases where using the datetime literal syntax will not work.  Off the top of my head I don't remember which functions/procs throw a fit, but because of that reason I recommend never using this approach when trying to store datetime values to macro vars.

Answer (score 0):

Your posted macro variable works fine in SAS code.

```
82   %let mydate = "01JUN2021 00:00:00.000"dt;
83
84   data test;
85    now = datetime();
86    then = &mydate;
87    diff = intck('dtday',then ,now);
88    format now then datetime20. ;
89    put (_all_) (=);
90   run;

now=16JUN2021:08:18:33 then=01JUN2021:00:00:00 diff=15
NOTE: The data set WORK.TEST has 1 observations and 3 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

If you need to use the value in pass through SQL code then you will need to set the macro variable to text that the remote database's implementation of SQL will recognize as a datetime value.

So perhaps

```
%let myts = timestamp '2021-06-01 00:00:00.000';
```